# How to execute Jess in php

Tags: php, jess

Can someone help me with integration Java Expert System Shell with php? I just want to execute some jess file (.clp) in php code, but I'm not sure if this is possible. I'm not an expert of php neither jess.

Comment: More informations:

Comment: More informations: I'm trying to implement a web based expert system. I've written the code on clips, but the program has to run from the command line. Also my goal is to get input from a html form, assert the input as a fact, run java expert system with new facts, and display results on the form.

Comment: Well, it'd be a heck of a lot easier if your web site were coded in Java; you could then simply use Jess's well-documented Java API. From PHP, using Jess will be just as difficult as using CLIPS: you're running an external program written in a different language.

Comment: You might implement a Java application running Jess (as Ernest suggested) as a server, send requests from the PHP client, return results for displaying in the client.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Ok. Can you also tell me, it would be easier to implement java application running jess as a server and interact it with CMS(Magento) or implement whole web shop & jess application in spring?

Comment: You are asking for decisions that require detailed knowledge of the business application you are planning to build. Also note that Jess is not open source, so you/your customer(s) may have to buy (a) license(s).